# Flutter: What kind of parameter type can have the argument type 'Image Function(dynamic)' assigned to it?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I'm just trying to load an image. I'm using the beta channel with web support. Flutter 1.19.0-4.3.pre. Dart 2.9.0

This is my pubspec:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

And this is my main.dart;

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png')),
          ] < Widget > [
            Text('Find happy, temporary, homes for your pets'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which I just copy/pasted from the documentation on the Flutter website. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have `two arrays in a single <Widget>[]` Column Class. I can see that you have done this:

```
<Widget>[
    Image(image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png')),
] < Widget > [
    Text('Find happy, temporary, homes for your pets'),
],
```

Which is indeed wrong. What a normal `Column()` accepts is like this. **[To read more about Column class, please click [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)]**

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    // You multiple widget goes here not in multiple arrays
    Widget1
    Widget2
    ...
  ]
)
```

So to correct your code, you should do something like this, else, you have done correct in respect of `assets`

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          // One single array keeps your multiple widgets
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png')),
            Text('Find happy, temporary, homes for your pets'),
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know, if that works for you. Happy learning :)

Comment: Happy to help @tdrsam. All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `pubspec.yaml` file's indentations are correct:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

And then for your `main.dart` I think you don't need the Widget Builder. So your `main.dart` should look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've got a feeling I'm just missing something small. I edited the code in the original question. I suspect I'm not getting the image and text widgets right.